# How can you prevent flicker when changing the href of a stylesheet link?

Tags: bootstrap-4

The scenario is a theme switcher. In my case, it is for bootstrap using bootswatch themes.

```
  <script src="/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
  <link id="theme-styles" href="/bootswatch/dist/darkly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The code for switching is simple:

```
  const themeName = themeSelector.value;
  $('#theme-styles').attr('href', `/bootswatch/dist/${themeName}/bootstrap.min.css`);
```

The themeSelector is a select element (dropdown) with the list of themes. When arrowing up and down through the list, the page flickers. You can see the default styles (or lack thereof) being applied before the new href goes into effect.

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised that I could not find an answer to this issue. Sure, it's not that big a deal. But the flicker bothered me and I knew it could be smoother. The problem would likely be worse using a CDN so I decided to solve it myself. It's actually pretty simple. Here's my actual code complete with comment:

```
  const handleThemeSelectorChange = (s,e) => {
    const themeName = themeSelector.value;
    const href = `/bootswatch/dist/${themeName}/bootstrap.min.css`;

    // Changing the href of a stylesheet link immediately takes that stylesheet out 
    // of the set of styles and the default styles will be applied in the interval 
    // between the new href and the old href. The effect is a noticeable flicker as 
    // elements change size, shape, and color. We can work around this by creating a
    // new stylesheet with the new href and sliding it below the original 
    // stylesheet. We then give it a just a few milliseconds to apply the new styles
    // before removing the original stylesheet. If we change the theme rapid fire, 
    // we could wind up with several old stylesheets for just a beat. But we're 
    // using jQuery to remove them all, leaving only the new one. The effect is a 
    // much smoother transition between themes.
    const ts = $('#theme-styles');
    const ss = ts.clone();
    ts.attr('id', 'old-theme');
    ss.attr('href', href);
    ts.after(ss);
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#old-theme').remove()
      }, 300)
    window.localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
  }
```